# TAB just produces TAB-space when using emacs -nw and matlab-shell

Tags: matlab, emacs

I am trying to run matlab-shell in emacs, and everything seems to be working if I run the GUI version of emacs. But because I am logging in remotely, I prefer to run emacs in the "-nw" mode so that I don't need to deal with delay due to GUI.

The problem I run into right now (under emacs -nw) is that when I am in matlab-shell, if I hit TAB, instead of giving me a list of functions to choose from, or auto-completing the directory/filenames, it just produce a TAB-space...

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am not familiar with elisp so not sure how to work around it.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
(add-hook
 'matlab-shell-mode-hook
 (lambda()
   (define-key matlab-shell-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 
     'matlab-shell-tab)))
```

Comment: Note that it reflects a bug in matlab.el, so please report it to the author.